# Ubuntu Server Disk Space Recommendation

Tags: server, partitioning, 20.04, home-directory

I'm installing Ubuntu Server 20.04 for a Home Server and small website hosting. Should 50 GB disk space be enough? How much disk space should i give to my `/home` and `/var` partitions?
Would it work with SSH?

Comment: anything in [this resource](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-system-requirements) you might find useful?

Comment: The Ubuntu Server default settings are safe and sane for your described sort of setup. Why are you not using those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu (Server) itself is using about 2-4GB, and if you only store/run a small web page 50GB should be more than enough. Upgrading your disk to a larger one isn't that hard in Ubuntu, and it's even easier if you have a 2nd computer.

Edit: You don't have to make extra partitions for /home and /var, but if you want to, I think 15-20GB each should be fine